# How can I attached a BPF program to a kernel function via a kprobe?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kernel, bpf, ebpf

The Cilium [BPF and XDP Reference Guide](http://docs.cilium.io/en/latest/bpf/) describes how you can load a BPF program to a netdevice via the `ip` and `tc` commands. How would I attach a BPF program to a kernel function/userspace function in the same way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL;DR** You can use the traditional [kprobe API](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/trace/kprobetrace.txt) to trace a function, then `perf_event_open` + `ioctl` to attach a BPF program.

This is implemented in [the `load_and_attach` function](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/35277995e17919ab838beae765f440674e8576eb/samples/bpf/bpf_load.c#L131-L207) of file `load_bpf.c` in the kernel, and in [the `bpf_attach_kprobe`](https://github.com/iovisor/bcc/blob/5d415c3679ee876338d57cd658b958b89bd008df/src/cc/libbpf.c#L787) and [`bpf_attach_tracing_event` function](https://github.com/iovisor/bcc/blob/5d415c3679ee876338d57cd658b958b89bd008df/src/cc/libbpf.c#L726) of file `libbpf.c` in bcc.

---

You can see this in action when tracing [the `hello_world.py` from bcc](https://github.com/iovisor/bcc/blob/e6c75684cbea7a2435fbae395699292414640524/examples/hello_world.py):

```
$ strace -s 100 python examples/hello_world.py
[...]
bpf(BPF_PROG_LOAD, {prog_type=BPF_PROG_TYPE_KPROBE, insn_cnt=15, insns=0x7f35716217d0, license="GPL", log_level=0, log_size=0, log_buf=0, kern_version=265728}, 72) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/sys/bus/event_source/devices/kprobe/type", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/sys/bus/event_source/devices/kprobe/format/retprobe", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/sys/kernel/debug/tracing/kprobe_events", O_WRONLY|O_APPEND) = 4
getpid()                                = 8121
write(4, "p:kprobes/p_sys_clone_bcc_8121 sys_clone", 40) = 40
close(4)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/sys/kernel/debug/tracing/events/kprobes/p_sys_clone_bcc_8121/id", O_RDONLY) = 4
read(4, "1846\n", 4096)                 = 5
close(4)                                = 0
perf_event_open({type=PERF_TYPE_TRACEPOINT, size=0 /* PERF_ATTR_SIZE_??? */, config=1846, ...}, -1, 0, -1, PERF_FLAG_FD_CLOEXEC) = 4
mmap(NULL, 36864, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, 4, 0) = 0x7f356c58b000
ioctl(4, PERF_EVENT_IOC_SET_BPF, 0x3)   = 0
ioctl(4, PERF_EVENT_IOC_ENABLE, 0)      = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/sys/kernel/debug/tracing/trace_pipe", O_RDONLY) = 5
fstat(5, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0444, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
fstat(5, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0444, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
read(5,
```

1. The first syscall (`bpf`) loads the BPF program in the kernel.
2. Then bcc follows the kprobe API to trace `sys_clone` by writing `p:kprobes/p_sys_clone_bcc_8121 sys_clone` in `p:kprobes/p_sys_clone_bcc_8121 sys_clone`.
3. bcc retrieves, in `p:kprobes/p_sys_clone_bcc_8121 sys_clone`, an ID to use in `perf_event_open`.
4. bcc calls `perf_event_open` with type `PERF_TYPE_TRACEPOINT`
5. and attaches the loaded BPF program (referenced by fd `0x3`) to that perf_event, with an `PERF_EVENT_IOC_SET_BPF` ioctl.